# Avoiding duplicate Developer Tool panel instances

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to create a devtools extension, starting with adding a panel. I'm simply calling `chrome.devtools.panels.create` from an external script loaded onto my extension's page. But when I select the toolbar button for my extension, a new instance of the panel is created with a corresponding button appearing to the right of the original. Selecting that new button instance repeats the behavior.

I've followed [Google's example](https://developer.chrome.com/stable/extensions/devtools.panels.html) and a [detailed blog post](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/7/15/How-to-add-a-panel-to-Chrome-Dev-Tools), but in neither of them am I seeing anything where this should be called from an event listener. I also can't find any way of detecting other instances of the panel, so I'm not sure how to avoid this issue. I'm not sure if I've possibly run into a new bug, or I'm overlooking something fundamental here...

Comment: I assume you got a -1 on this question because you neglected to add your relevant code.  That's really what will help people answer your question.  The fact that I, too, had this problem, I **think** I can answer it without your code. For future questions, however, you should tell us what you've tried and include the code you used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.  My problem was that I had a loop of calling that `panels.create()` method.

### Inducing the loop

My `manifest.json` file showed:

```
"devtools_page": "devtools.html"
```

My `devtools.html` included `devtools.js`, which called `panels.create()` like this:

```
chrome.devtools.panels.create('Title', 'iconfile', 'devtools.html');
```

This was the issue because my `panels.create()` method was creating a new panel consisting of `devtools.html` which would recall `panels.create()` in a loop.

### Fixing the loop

This method should call a separate `html` file that will house all of your actual panel content, like:

```
chrome.devtools.panels.create('Title', 'iconfile', 'panel.html');
```

`panel.html` cannot include `devtools.js` or you'll have the same issue again.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Finally got back to this project, this was exactly the same issue I had ran into. Thank you for sharing your solution!

Comment: Glad it helped! I remember this issue frustrating me a lot, so I wanted to share! Good luck.